# Green screen elements coming out white washed

Tags: texturing, image

[image: green screen element comparison]

I'm trying to add some green screen elements to a scene and for some reason every element has been coming out completely white. I've been doing this project for almost four months and this only started happening last night. I do every single element the exact same way and as you can see some elements are white and some are fine. In the image there are two different images as planes just to show the problem. If anyone knows what might have happened i would greatly appreciate it thank you

Comment: Set base color to black in principled BSDF

Comment: that did help a bit thank you